# preg_quote and preg_match leaving in the escaped \'s

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code:

```
$replacement = array("$12.00", "Sue-ellen");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($replacement); $i++) {
    $replacement[$i] = preg_quote($replacement[$i]);
}

$message = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $message);
```

I am expecting `$message` to be "Hi Sue-ellen here is $12.00" however it returns "Hi Sue\-ellen here is $12\.00"

I'm wondering why it leaves the escape characters in, and how to get around it.

I'm currently using `$message = preg_replace("/\\/", "", $message);` after as a stop-gap but I'm sure that there's a more "elegant" way. Because there may be a use case in the future where they wish to use `\` in an input.

**EDIT**

```
$message = "Hi <firstname> here is <value>"
```

Changed to `preg_quote($regex)` where `$regex = array('/<firstname>/i', '/<value>/i');`

This resulted in

```
$message = "Hi Sue-ellen here is 2.00"
```

Comment: You only need to escape special characters in the regular expression, not in the replacement.

Comment: What the contents of the original `$message`, if its just str replacement why not use str_replace or sprintf?

Comment: have updated with requested info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_quote` is for escaping characters that have special meaning in regular expressions. The replacement string isn't parsed for these escape sequences, they're kept literally.

It looks like you're trying to prevent `$12` in `$12.00` from being treated as a back-reference to a capture group. This is the only special sequence in the replacement string. A function for escaping this can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#106263)

```
// Escape backreferences from string for use with regex 
function preg_escape_back($string) { 
    // Replace $ with \$ and \ with \\ 
    $string = preg_replace('#(?<!\\\\)(\\$|\\\\)#', '\\\\$1', $string); 
    return $string; 
}
```

So you can do:

```
$replacement = array_map('preg_escape_back', $replacement);
```

Comment: This worked. Had to change `map` to `array_map` though.